# Convert string to set array when loading csv file in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, set

I'm trying to convert a pandas column from string to a set so I can perform `set` operations (`-`) and methods (`.union`) between two datafame on two set_array columns. The files are imported from **two** csv file with a set_array column. However, once I run `pd.read_csv` in pandas, the columns type becomes `str`, which prevents me from doing set operations and methods.

csv1:

```
        set_array
0       {985,784}
1       {887}
2       set()
3       {123,469,789}
4       set()
```

After loading csv1 into a DataFrame using `df = pd.read_csv(csv1)`, the data type becomes `str`, and when I try to call the first index using `df['set_array'].values[0]`, I get the following:

```
'{985, 784}'
```

However, if I were to create my own DataFrame with a `set` column using `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'set_array':[{985, 784},{887},{},{123, 469, 789},{}]})`, and call the first index again using `df['set_array'].values[0]`, I get the following **(Desired output)**:

```
{985, 784} <-without the ''
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```
1) df.replace('set()', '') <-removes the set() portion from df
2) df['set_array'] = df['set_array'].apply(set) <-does not work
3) df['set_array'] = df['set_array'].apply(lambda x: {x}) <-does not work
4) df['set_array'].astype(int) <-convert to int first then convert to set, does not work
5) df['set_array'].astype(set) <-does not work
6) df['set_array'].to_numpy() <-convert to array, does not work
```

I'm also thinking to change the column to set at the pd.read_csv stage as a potential solution.

Is there any way to load csv using pandas and keep the `set` data type, or just simply convert the column from `str` to `set` so it looks like the **desired output** above?

Thanks!!

Comment: `df.set_array.apply(eval)` would evaluate the column as python code and covert it directly to set types. It's pretty clumsy, and using eval is generally bad practice (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) but it would be the shortest route to the outcome you desire, assuming you're pretty sure about the input data and this is one-off code/not for production.

Comment: Thanks @fordy! I did see this as a solution, and it did resolve my issue. However, I do plan to use this for production, will this be an issue since i'm only using it number arrays only?

Comment: I really recommend not saving your csv file with set in columns. If your want to use other data types than string, int or bool, you can save your files using `pickle`, which preserves the data types (like lists and set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your DataFrame is that *set_array* contains
the text representation of **both**:

- set literals,
- *Python* code.

To cope with this case:

1. `import ast`.
2. Define the following conversion function:

   ```
   def mySetConv(txt):
       return set() if txt == 'set()' else ast.literal_eval(txt)
   ```
3. Apply it:

   ```
   df.set_array = df.set_array.apply(mySetConv)
   ```

To check the result, you can run:

```
for it in df.set_array:
    print(it, type(it))
```

getting:

```
{784, 985} <class 'set'>
{887} <class 'set'>
set() <class 'set'>
{789, 123, 469} <class 'set'>
set() <class 'set'>
```

If you had in your source file `{}` instead of `set()`, you
could run:

```
df.set_array = df.set_array.apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Just a **single** line of code.

Comment: Thanks @Valdi! Quick question, how does the earlier answer with ```.apply(eval)``` differ from your solution using ```.apply(ast.literal_eval)``` as they both solve the ```set()``` and the ```{}``` issue?

Comment: "Ordinary" *eval* is less safe. It allows for *code injection*, so it is safer to use *ast.literal_eval*. Even one of comments to your post contains *using eval is generally bad practice*.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Cainã that dealing with the root input data cause would be the best approach here. But, if that's not possible, then something like this would be a lot more predictable than using `eval` if this is for some kind of production environment:

```
import re

def parse_set_string(s):
    if s == 'set()':
        return None  # or return set() if you prefer
    else:
        string_nums_only = re.sub('[^0-9,]', '', s)  
        split_nums = string_nums_only.split(',')
        return set(map(int, split_nums))

    
df.set_array.apply(parse_set_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

We've seen this problem before when  columns originally contained lists or numpy arrays.  `csv` is a 2d format - rows and columns.  So `to_csv` can only save these embedded objects as strings. What does the file look like?.

`read_csv` by default just loads the strings.  To confuse things further, the pandas display does not quote strings.  So the `str` of a set looks the same as the set itself.

With lists, it's enough to do a `eval` (or `ast.literal_eval`).  With `ndarray` the string has to be edited first.

Make a dataframe and fill it with some objects:

```
In [107]: df = pandas.DataFrame([None,None,None])
In [108]: df
Out[108]: 
      0
0  None
1  None
2  None
In [109]: df[0][0]
In [110]: df[0][0]=[1,2,3]
In [111]: df[0][1]=np.array([1,2,3])
In [112]: df[0][2]={1,2,3}
In [113]: df
Out[113]: 
           0
0  [1, 2, 3]
1  [1, 2, 3]
2  {1, 2, 3}
```

The `numpy` equivalent:

```
In [114]: df.to_numpy()
Out[114]: 
array([[list([1, 2, 3])],
       [array([1, 2, 3])],
       [{1, 2, 3}]], dtype=object)
```

Write it to a file:

```
In [115]: df.to_csv('test.pd')
In [116]: cat test.pd
,0
0,"[1, 2, 3]"
1,[1 2 3]
2,"{1, 2, 3}"
```

Read it

```
In [117]: df1 = pandas.read_csv('test.pd')
In [118]: df1
Out[118]: 
   Unnamed: 0          0
0           0  [1, 2, 3]
1           1    [1 2 3]
2           2  {1, 2, 3}
```

Ignoring the indexing that I  should have suppressed, it looks a lot like the original `df`.  But it contains strings, not list, array, or set.

```
In [119]: df1.to_numpy()
Out[119]: 
array([[0, '[1, 2, 3]'],
       [1, '[1 2 3]'],
       [2, '{1, 2, 3}']], dtype=object)
```

Changing the frame to contains sets of differing sizes:

```
In [120]: df[0][1]=set()
In [122]: df[0][0]=set([1])
In [123]: df
Out[123]: 
           0
0        {1}
1         {}
2  {1, 2, 3}
In [124]: df.to_csv('test.pd')
In [125]: cat test.pd
,0
0,{1}
1,set()
2,"{1, 2, 3}"

In [136]: df2 =pandas.read_csv('test.pd',index_col=0)
In [137]: df2
Out[137]: 
           0
0        {1}
1      set()
2  {1, 2, 3}
```

Looks like `eval` can convert the empty set as well as the others:

```
In [138]: df3  =df2['0'].apply(eval)
In [139]: df3
Out[139]: 
0          {1}
1           {}
2    {1, 2, 3}
Name: 0, dtype: object
In [140]: df2.to_numpy()
Out[140]: 
array([['{1}'],
       ['set()'],
       ['{1, 2, 3}']], dtype=object)
In [141]: df3.to_numpy()
Out[141]: array([{1}, set(), {1, 2, 3}], dtype=object)
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. The part with pandas not displaying quote strings in dataframe is clear with me after some testing on my end. Your solution mentioned that ```eval``` is enough with list, but what about ```sets``` in my case, where I have any a set array?